# How can I make this Javascript code more efficient?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

Everything works like I want, but I feel I'm being redundant. I have 100 more videos to upload and feel there is a better way than to continue to make functions: ninetyNine(), oneHundred().

**Javascript**

```
<script> 
function first(){
    $('#videoObj').remove();
    $('<iframe id="videoObj"  width="1280 " height="720" src="http://www.mysiteetisym.com/videos/KidsOnTrampoline.mp4"  frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>').prependTo('#vholder');
}
function second(){
    $('#videoObj').remove();
    $('<iframe id="videoObj" width="1280" height="720" src="http://www.mysiteetisym.com/videos/WaterFight.mp4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>').prependTo('#vholder');
}

function third(){
    $('#videoObj').remove();
    $('<iframe id="videoObj" width="1280 " height="720" src="http://www.mysiteetisym.com/videos/FourWheelingRace.mp4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>').prependTo('#vholder');
}

function fourth(){
    $('#videoObj').remove();
    $('<iframe id="videoObj"  width="1280 " height="720" src="http://www.mysiteetisym.com/videos/CookingWithDebbie.mp4"  frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>').prependTo('#vholder');
}
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
<div>
  <input class="videoBtns" id="firstVideo" type="image" src="images/KidsOnTrampoline.jpg" onClick="first()" />
  <input class="videoBtns" id="secondVideo" type="image" src="images/WaterFight.jpg" onClick="second()" />
  <input class="videoBtns" id="thirdVideo" type="image" src="images/FourWheelingRace.jpg" onClick="third()" />
  <input class="videoBtns" id="fourthVideo" type="image" src="images/CookingWithDebbie.jpg "onClick="fourth()" />
</div>

<div id="vholder"></div>

</body>
```

Comment: How about a single function that accepts a parameter for the name of the video?

Comment: @Pointy - That is my goal, to turn everything into a single function. I'm learning about JSON files at the moment and it seems to be efficient to load data from them. I'm just a trial and error guy who has reached my final error.

Comment: @Marcus, you don't need JSON for that, look at given answers

Comment: @iArcadia - I know JSON is not needed. I'm learning it because I have a lot of attributes with each video. Name, location, people, time, date, etc. My ultimate goal is to click on the .jpg of the video, and all that meta data list under the video.

Comment: No problem, I misunderstood your comment

Answer (score 0):

Pass the src as a parameter and append it in the function to the iframe. Call one function only

```js
function f(e){
    $('#videoObj').remove();
    $('<iframe id="videoObj"  width="1280 " height="720" src=http://www.mysiteetisym.com/videos/'+e+'.mp4  frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>').prependTo('#vholder');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div>
  <input class="videoBtns" id="firstVideo" type="image" src="images/KidsOnTrampoline.jpg" onClick="f('KidsOnTrampoline')" />
  <input class="videoBtns" id="secondVideo" type="image" src="images/WaterFight.jpg" onClick="f('WaterFight')" />
  <input class="videoBtns" id="thirdVideo" type="image" src="images/FourWheelingRace.jpg" onClick="f('FourWheelingRace')" />
  <input class="videoBtns" id="fourthVideo" type="image" src="images/CookingWithDebbie.jpg "onClick="f('CookingWithDebbie')" />
</div>

<div id="vholder"></div>

</body>
```

Comment: Although not significant of a change, you can simply it further seeing that most of the URL is the same for all of the videos.

Comment: @k97513 - It works, and thank you! Is there any other way to to make the input buttons more efficient? I'm running into the same problem of writing 100 lines of code for each video.

Answer (score 0):

Try with click event with dom instead of inline

1. Each time click .Get the clicked input elem src
2. Then match the exact result using regex
3. Then pass with iframe source

```js
$(document).on('click','.videoBtns',function(){
   $('#videoObj').remove();
   var vid = $(this).attr('src').toString().match(/\/(.*)\./g)[0];
   console.log("http://www.mysiteetisym.com/videos"+vid+
"mp4")
    $('<iframe id="videoObj"  width="1280 " height="720" src="http://www.mysiteetisym.com/videos'+vid+'mp4"  frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>').prependTo('#vholder');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input class="videoBtns" id="firstVideo" type="image" src="images/KidsOnTrampoline.jpg"  />
  <input class="videoBtns" id="secondVideo" type="image" src="images/WaterFight.jpg" />
  <input class="videoBtns" id="thirdVideo" type="image" src="images/FourWheelingRace.jpg"  />
  <input class="videoBtns" id="fourthVideo" type="image" src="images/CookingWithDebbie.jpg " />
</div>

<div id="vholder"></div>
```